# angularjs longpolling for mail app

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax, long-polling

I'm going to make a mailbox with angular js so i have a service and a controller that manage the mails.

**Service**

```
app.service('mails',['$http','$interval','$rootScope',function($http,$interval,$rootScope){
      var updatedData;
      $interval(function(){
        return $http.post('inc/get_mails.php?user='+'<?php echo $_SESSION['user']; ?>')
        .success(function(response){
          updatedData = response;
          alert(updatedData);
          $rootScope.$broadcast('got new mail!', { data: updatedData });
        })
        .error(function(err){console.log(err);});
      },1000);
    }]);
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.$on('got new mail!', function(event, args) {
  $scope.mails = args.data;
});
```

but i have a problem this service does not run even 1 time. what should i do!? :(
tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in your service is not called, you have to inject your service in order to run it. But I think it's a better practice to create a method in your service to init your code, it's more explicit.

```
app.factory('mails',['$http','$interval','$rootScope',function($http,$interval,$rootScope){

      var updatedData = [];

      return {
         init: init
      }

      function init() {
        $interval(function(){
          return $http.post('inc/get_mails.php?user='+'<?php echo $_SESSION['user']; ?>')
          .success(function(response){
            // check if their is a difference between this call and the last call
            if (updatedData.length !== response.length) {
               updatedData = response;
               alert(updatedData);
               $rootScope.$broadcast('got new mail!', { data: updatedData });
            }
          })
          .error(function(err){console.log(err);});
        },1000);
      }

    }]);
```

And then if you want to run the code :

```
app.controller('yourCtrl', ['mails', '$scope', function(mails, $scope) {
   mails.init();

   // each time you have a new mail
   $scope.$on('got new mail!', function(event, args) {
       $scope.mails = args.data;
   });
}]);
```

Comment: sorry i did not noticed the changes in code. thanks for your answer i will check it out.

Comment: thank you so much Gatsbill, your init method made the magic :D. now it's working.

Comment: yes, i did not considered the changes. now it's working thank you;)

Comment: can i check the array changes to notify for new mails!?

Comment: that's what you do with: '$scope.$on('got new mail!', function(event, args) {
  $scope.mails = args.data;
});' not sure what your asking

Comment: i'm going to show a notification if a new message received!